# Changing the frontend language & multiple countries support in Shopware

Tags: shopware

So, I'm trying to understand how this E-Commerce solution works. I have installed the Community Edition and added the default shop. Everything is fine. I read in the Shopware documentation that you can add multiple languages to the web shop by creating additional shops and configuring them as Language Shops. All is fine, that worked, I now have two websites.

Problem is - even though the localisation information is set to Romanian - the website is all in German. Do I really need to purchase the language packs that are offered in the Shopware store? Or can I change the text manually? If so, how do you do that? Also, apparently the flag for the selected language is off... I have the Language Shop configured for RO, but it displays the shop as DE (Germany).

Also, can Shopware make a difference between selected languages when talking about product stock, prices and payment method? The idea is that depending on what country is selected, the product stock and price is changed. With this, the product code might get changed. Also, payment methods and accounts have to be changed as well. Can Shopware do that? If so, is there a tutorial or something regarding this? (I didn't really find something like this...)

Thanks for the help !

---

Crossposted at the [Shopware Community Forum](https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/42945/changing-the-frontend-language-multiple-countries-support-in-shopware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many questions ... trying to sort this out:

1. As far as I know the backend is available in 2 languages only, German and Englisch.
2. Just changing the localisation will not change the language being used in the shop frontend. Changing the language is a complex thing to do, which require many aspects.
3. First of all, each subshop is assigned to a root category eg. 'German' or 'English' or 'Romanian' - this facilitates to show different stock in different languages. (Btw, do not delete the category Deutsch or German, it will break the system. If you don't need it, just leave it empty.)
4. Many of the predefined attributes and any custom defined attribute for articles can be translated.
5. Any other static text can be translated, as Shopware uses the Smarty template technology - very easy and straightforward to do.

Bottom line: No you do not need to buy the language packs, if you want to the translation yourself.

Prices can be set per customer group, subshops in turn are associated to customer groups, so this way you could show different prices in different regions/languages.

Comment: Additional info, even if this is a bit late, subshops have own stocks and articles has to be setup to the shop. reason: sometimes there are article what can be sold in germany but its not allowed to sell them in/to other countries :)